# class not found error in rmic compile

Tags: java, rmi

I use rmi class and I have one problem. My interface's name is `server` and my implementing class's name is `serverImpl`. When i type `rmic -v1.2 -classpath .. serverImpl` in command line (after compiling interface and classes) it shows this error:

```
error: Class serverImpl not found.
```

I checked that `serverImpl` exists in the specified directory.

Comment: Please provide more information about your packages hierarchy and about the classpath here.

Comment: interface server,class serverImpl,class account,class mainserver

Answer (score 6):

1. Put your server class and the implemented class in a folder, name it `x`
2. Add this package on top of each class `package x;`
3. Open cmd and write `javac x/MyServer.java` and `javac x/MyImpl.java` from the directory that contain the `x` folder.
4. Write `rmic x.MyServer` from the directory that contain the `x` folder.
5. You should have now a `MyServer_stub.class` and you can have a nice day :)

PS: It is important that the package name is different than RMI or any object used inside the class. Otherwise you will have object collision.

Answer (score 0):

`serverImpl` doesn't have to 'exist in the specified directory'. You haven't specified a directory, you have specified a CLASSPATH, and `serverImpl` has to exist within that, under the appropriate package structure, which you also have to name correctly in the command line. So if `serverImpl` is in package `x.y`, you have to specify a CLASSPATH that contains the x/y directory, and specify `x.y.serverImpl` on the command line. Exactly as you do when running with the 'java' command.

But you haven't needed `rmic` at all for about eight years - see the class Javadoc for `UnicastRemoteObject`.

Comment: Received your flag, noting irregular on our radar. I blame browsing while intoxicated.

Answer (score -2):

Please convert the slashes (/) to dots(.). It worked for me.

I have following structure

```
rmitest/
rmitest/MyRemoteIf.java
rmitest/MyRemoteImpl.java

javac rmitest/*.java

rmic rmitest.MyRemoteImpl
```

The output was :

```
rmitest/MyRemoteIf.class

rmitest/MyRemoteImpl.class

rmitest/MyRemoteImpl_Stub.class

rmitest/MyRemoteImpl_Skel.class
```

Good Luck!!
Karan

Comment: Please explain why this conversion would solve the OP's error

Comment: It is looking for the package name when we run the class. Because the package name are separated by dots(.)